# Screen navigate from stacknavigator not showing bottomtabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i've got a bottomtabnavigator and a stacknavigator. When i navigate to a screen in stacknavigator, bottomtabnavigator is not showing in the screen. is there a way to show the bottomtabnavigator in screens from stacknavigator?

Below is my navigator codes:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  MainTabNavigator
);

const stackScreens = createStackNavigator({
    profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
    loginform: {screen: LoginFormScreen},
    merchant: {screen : merchantScreen},
    registerform: {screen: RegisterFormScreen},
    offer:{screen: offerScreen},
});

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
    TabNavigator,
    stackScreens,
});
```

Comment: In order to answer we need to know the structure you are planning for your navigation. How many tabs should there be? Should the tabBar be on all screens? Should all screens be avaiable from all tabs?

Comment: @Zayco after thinking through again, it does not make sense for all screens to have the bottom tabs. my app does not requires all screens have to be in tab bars. i've relook into the documents and think through the process. now i understand that only screens that is created in createBottomTabNavigator will have tab navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken from [the react navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab) and it gives a good example of how to combine stackNavigators and tabNavigators

[see the full snack for a working example](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/stacks-in-tabs-v3)

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

export default createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
  },
));
```